# Add a new row in mysql database through wordpress using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Im pretty new in this and I have some problems with wordpress.

Im trying to insert some information to mysql database. So for that Im doing the following:

First I created a php file in `wp-content/plugins/my-codes` and the file name is insertUser.php where I added the following code:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "Users";
$name=addslashes($_POST['sName']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['sEmail']);
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( '$name','$email' ) );
?>
```

Then I created a basic page with the following:

```
<form action="/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/insertUser.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="sName" />
Email: <input type="text" name="sEmail" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now the problem is that when I fill up the form and press the submit button is redirecting me to `http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/insertUser.php` and not insterting any row in the database.

Any ideas of what Im doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
<?php 
include '../../../wp-config.php';
global $wpdb;    
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name=addslashes($_POST['sName']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['sEmail']);
$wpdb->insert("Users",array(
    "sName"=>$name,
    "sEmail"=>$email,
    ));
}
```

?>

**EDIT config.php**

```
<?php
/**
* The base configuration for WordPress
*
* The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
* installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
* copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
*
* This file contains the following configurations:
*
* * MySQL settings
* * Secret keys
* * Database table prefix
* * ABSPATH
*
* @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
*
* @package WordPress
*/

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'foundint_wordpress3ed');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'foundint_word3ed');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XgY9PuLOgk7e');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
* Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
*
* Change these to different unique phrases!
* You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-    key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
*
* @since 2.6.0
*/
define('AUTH_KEY', 'w-+F%ar+H_KthUYw]O<GlY;LgKGe[(XY@auxk;ZYZD|    [}gx!%FAD)KkN}/WJWccym+- s;%Pa=P_hIszZr%$Mtyu)ugwfbju<lYdMrXKOo_>!eZ/$Nf(vHNzlb@on%M>D');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'x{pM!iVyNHWvYj$YYeeK-[UJLZDDrt%frd{Tj- YKAN]=tmJv=WMMmUgIFrQV{|-Jfm-dJnKxjsNs?tvZo/}TRJswh|^EaQVa;b%RBeZL= <k@h+kvES${@a$M(sseVEfh');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', '<?d)Lu@[oh}<Q&eVRnV+SiCPPk*HzP$(prfU;Co;wbc?PG+hJL/kJggiL[rxQph>ND(I|+k]uYyiOsb^)HIm<J$SVe^WiE>VHl*?N+S|&IM]BN|MPE_&)%O(s$sZCMm@');
define('NONCE_KEY', 'eGS+xFleYc[v]m@Gzy>KY/wbj[/lKtQ_ViIo]licFeyi(}hFfcachqJGHOlC@eZO@{Mq/hOLBTdxi]&Sk@Om<Qojbe+(-<waasHK=VjY)+J=tBwejj;voHF];We?XPiH');
define('AUTH_SALT', '-XF|WkVGk[%gY!S;tBFI>Y[J;v|A>ZbJT)G!R=T)bbAdsXn?<VMzyTIQECve@T{Rf}!rZXl}RdlaF?fz>HFXvnOwtl-/I]-B{(IlF+r+[UuKrkQ[<GCcs<tp+umtZXzZ');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '{]&Vlqy<wpAB_MUh!$RnjnTvH&jX$goRnZ)XlULL;zyxQcv*;dX=c=^>VsJBG<kElTCtKsw%RSOFBngSqPU}|uvy@/bS/c[[e)INP}jgNy^BV_G!D_}cK--qrP*bx*gq');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT', 'xP*[_am/}Pj?t@X{-<%?EY)sx>cs!bt)!d^zXs=vVY<LJ%B)PjlGDHy+Oi!iGIDv!}A_r;glYstXeI{YVR=?PofnBllW?_<t@{wE@Z[o?@UMBmMi-Fap>LEUj_;vZFdH');
define('NONCE_SALT', '_cPe>RB]Nq]j]aQfgWB@+$eLfYig@MGA&]nD&}?feKpkCm;v-MkEi-Dt_BWXWNV+QAVbFexDYlhWlJemTTo/bvKpAyjWqso<)kY}$}FR^G$mwIyvt$P]<M@Dv(wXGyhe');

/**#@-*/

/**
* WordPress Database Table prefix.
*
* You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
* a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
*/
$table_prefix = 'wp_nhgb_';

/**
* For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
*
* Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
* It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
* in their development environments.
*
* For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
* visit the Codex.
*
* @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
*/
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

**CODE EDIT**

```
<form action="/wp-content/plugins/my-codes/insertUser.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="sName" />
Email: <input type="text" name="sEmail" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Bro one idea. You don't redirect your page you just include that page in the same page if the submit button is pressed. It will work if you do like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow up the code below and it will insert the date into the database check whether the wp-config.php is three folders away alone others all you can copy an paste from here.

I have done the insert coding in the same page and you can copy paste the code for insert alone into the page you like.

```
<?php 
include '../../../wp-config.php';
global $wpdb;    
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name=addslashes($_POST['sName']);
    $email=addslashes($_POST['sEmail']);
    $wpdb->insert("test",array(
        "sName"=>$name,
        "sEmail"=>$email,
        ));
}    
?>   
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="sName" />
Email: <input type="text" name="sEmail" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There must be something that Im missing because I change the code as you suggest (see edit) and Im still not being able to insert anything in the database. I dont know...

Comment: Im very new to wordpress, so maybe Im forgeting to change some config file, or add a plugin or something? Is it possible?

Comment: Ya i understood. Could you better include the page what you have given in the form action when the button is pressed.

Comment: So that here you can do that `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ include ('required page')}` and you can write the code over to that page itself.

Comment: So, let me check if I understood. Do you suggest to add that line to the page? As php code? and keep calling the function?

Comment: It is very easy ya. You refer to the file that i have written for you in that i have written set of codes between `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//set of codes}`you just replace it with `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ include('insertUser.php'); }`

Comment: And write that addslashes and $wpdb->insert code along with database connectivity in that page 'insertUser.php'. That's sol.

Comment: Meanwhile provide the name for the **<input type="submit">** otherwise your code will not work.

Comment: Im sorry but im not following you. Do you want me to add the php code in the page and in the php the credentials for the db?

Comment: Can you do me a favor and check

Comment: Copy the file what i have sent you and c whether you can insert it into the database. Check to that your table name is correct in insert query and table field names.

Comment: I did it before, and it wasn't working. I copy the answer you post into the wordpress page and its still not working. I checked the data base and the values are correct. Im not able to upload a picture but here is: sName varchar(20), sEmail varchar(50) of the table Users

Comment: Ya better you do post the screenshot of the wp-config.php file and database.

Comment: @AlguienEnEsteMundo are you working in local or online.. If Online i will rectify it by myself and give you.

Comment: I cant I dont have enough reputation to add a screenshot. I havent touch the config file, should I?

Comment: It is mandatory while at the time of Wordpress installation it will be asking for the wp-config file right ..

Comment: Ya seen is this online or in local development

Comment: have you added the name for the **<input type="submit">**. Pls post the new codes that you have updated in your question . It is very easy to fix but we are hung up with this small issue..

Comment: So do I have to add the credentials to connect to the db in the config file? (edit added)

Comment: If I have the credentials for the db in the config file, then I'm going be saying which is the db, the username and password. Cause I just realized Im not writing that anywhere, so maybe thats the reason I dont have any error, and also no rows inserted. That make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Naresh Kumar.P for the help. Its necessary to change the config file with the credentials of the database to make the code work.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'yourDataBaseName');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'YourDataBaseUserName');

 /** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'YourDataBasePassword');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

And that's it. The code is correct!

Thanks!